# NPM Script for "node-sass" and "postcss" to autoprefix

Tags: npm, postcss, node-sass, npm-scripts

I need to compile my scss to css files with autoprefixing the attributes. My npm script looks like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "node-sass --output-style 'compressed' src/scss/ -o public_html/css/map/ && postcss --use autoprefixer public_html/css/map/ -d public_html/css/",
    "watch:css": "node-sass --watch --recursive --output-style 'compressed' src/scss/ -o public_html/css/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss": "^6.0.13",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

But I get a error message:

> `Plugin Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'`

At last i think that my code is dirty. I try to generate with node-sass the css files, and place them on filetree in "map" directory. Then i try to grab them with postcss and copy the autoprefixed css files in the css folder. Is there any cleaner way without creating the files in the map directory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the npm module: autoprefixer

```
npm install autoprefixer --save-dev
```